# Math calculations on two text fields

Tags: java

I have 3 test fields for input and calculation result. 4 buttons for the math operations and a action listener for each one.  I have a if statement to check which button i'm pressing but its not working and only the divide will work.

aa.java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


 public class aa extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
int c;


TextField text1,text2,text3;

Button button1,button2,button3,button4;
public void init()
{

text1 = new TextField(20);
add(text1);


text2 = new TextField(20);
add(text2);


text3 = new TextField(20);
add(text3);

button1 = new Button("add");
add(button1);
button1.addActionListener(this);

button2 = new Button("sub");
add(button2);
button2.addActionListener(this);

button3 = new Button("multiply");
add(button3);
button3.addActionListener(this);

button4 = new Button("divide");
add(button4);
button4.addActionListener(this);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
String str=e.getActionCommand();
int a=Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
int b=Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
if(str.equals("button1"))
{
c=a+b;
text3.setText(""+c);
}
else if(str.equals("button2"))
{
c=a+b;
text3.setText(""+c);
}
else if(str.equals("button3"))
{
c=a*b;
text3.setText(""+c);
}
else
{
c=a/b;
text3.setText(""+c);
}
}
}
```

aa.html

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<APPLET ALIGN="CENTER" CODE="aa.java" width = "500" height = "500"></APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: add action command (Look into Java API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method, you need to check for the button's `actionCommand` (by default the text it was constructed with), not its name (`"multiply"` rather than `"button2"`). You can change a button's action command with [`setActionCommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29)).

See [this page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JButtonsetActionCommandStringtext.htm) for more details.